# Setting background image size for samsung smart tv application?

Tags: css, samsung-smart-tv

I am creating an application for the samsung smart tv. The problem I am facing rite now is with the emulator version 2.5. This emulator version is using the maple browser and I have checked and found out that Maple browser is not using the CSS 'background-size' property. Can somebody please tell me how I can use this size property for Maple? I don't want to use the image tag in my application.

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a javascript based equivalent since that browser doesn't support CSS3 as far as I can see.

Here's a couple of examples:

http://louisremi.github.com/jquery.backgroundSize.js/demo/

http://nooshu.com/jquery-plug-in-scalable-background-image

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript solution as @BillyMoat mention - but in my opinion the best way is to use normal `img` tag as SmartTVs have very limited performance.

Adding to much JavaScript operations on DOM can just hang your application.